# Calling constructor of extended class

Tags: java, android, interface, android-activity, adapter

I have this class :

```
public class BaseFilterableArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter< IFilterableEntity<T> > implements SectionIndexer 
{


    public BaseFilterableArrayAdapter(Activity context,int id_row_template,  List<IFilterableEntity<T>> data)
    {
        super(context, id_row_template, data);
    }
```

the next class extends the previous class and this is its constructor:

```
public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<MyEntity> data) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_row, data);    
        ....
    }
```

**(MyEntity class implements IFilterableEntity <String>)**

problem is that I got error

```
The constructor `BaseFilterableArrayAdapter<String>(Activity, int, List<MyEntity>)` is undefined
```

How can I call the constructor of **BaseFilterableArrayAdapter** from **MyAdapter**?

Comment: Pay attention to the third argument `List<IFilterableEntity<T>>`vs `List<MyEntity>`are these two connected in any way the `IFilterableEntity<T>` and `MyEntity`?

Comment: You should also post how you declared the class. The error states that It wants a templated class.

Comment: You need first to reorganize your `List<MyEntity>` into `List<IFilterableEntity<T>>`

Comment: Change your extends to  MyAdapter extends BaseFilterableArrayAdapteryMyEntity> then it should work

Answer (score 1):

Generics are invariant so `List<MyEntity>` is not the same type as `List<IFilterableEntity<T>`. You could make the super class itself generic and make the sub class contain a `<MyEntity<T>` generic type argument

```
public class BaseFilterableArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> 
                                                     implements SectionIndexer{

    public BaseFilterableArrayAdapter(Activity context, int idRowTemplate, List<T> data) {
        super(context, idRowTemplate, data);
        ...         
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've added some code to my post for the class BaseFilterableArrayAdapter. Now the problem is, that it says: `The constructor ArrayAdapter<IFilterableEntity<T>>(Activity, int, List<capture#1-of ? extends IFilterableEntity<?>>) is undefined `

Comment: since ArrayAdapter uses a generic type argument you can't mix them with wilcards. you could change the generic type argument to allow the derived class (MyAdapter) arguments to match as shown

Answer (score 0):

It's a known Java pain-in-the-ass. Look at the following code:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Animal {

}

class Cat extends Animal {

}

public class TemplatedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    }
}
```

It won't compile:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Cat> to ArrayList<Animal>

    at TemplatedList.main(TemplatedList.java:14)
```

Unfortunatelly you have to convert it manually before passing to superconstructor.

Comment: See "Generics are not covariant" section of this document for more detail: http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/java/java-theory-generic-050323-1322/